# Как написать такой код на PHP с использованием оператора <=>

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка, условия, max

Не судите строго я начинающий PHP разработчик, как написать такой код, на PHP ?

```
s=["Ceylon", "Fish", "Apple", "MongoDB"]
 v=[]
 v=s.max{|t,u| t.size<=>u.size}
 puts v
```

Comment: Найти самые длинные слова в массиве, и сохранить их в новый массив, а потом и вывести типа echo $var;

Comment: @Эдуард не сработает ваш код

Comment: @Эдуард если я правильно понял, то по данному массиву вывод должен быть следующим [MongoDB,Ceylon, Apple, Fish]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сколько я понял - вас интересует сортировка массива:

```
$arr = ["Ceylon", "Fish", "Apple", "MongoDB"];

usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    return mb_strlen($b) <=> mb_strlen($a);
});

print_r($arr);
```

Результат:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => MongoDB 
    [1] => Ceylon 
    [2] => Apple 
    [3] => Fish 
)
```

Comment: Найти самые длинные слова, и сохранить в новый массив, код я написал на ruby.

Comment: Спасибо вам это тоже мне в копилку знаний.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = ["Ceylon", "Fish", "Apple", "MongoDB"]; 

function string_sort($a, $b){
    if (strlen($a) < strlen($b)) {
      return 1; 
    } elseif (strlen($a) == strlen($b)) { 
      return 0; 
    } else { 
      return -1; 
    }
}

usort($arr, 'string_sort');

var_dump($arr);
```

Попробуйте так

Comment: У вас интересный код, вы можете сделать такой же только подробно раскомментировать ? просто мне не со всем понятно, зачем мы после каждой проверки, указываем return ,  if (strlen($a) < strlen($b)) {
      return 1; 
    } elseif (strlen($a) == strlen($b)) { 
      return 0; 
    } else { 
      return -1; 
    }