# Хочу понять этот код на PHP, особенно зачем оператор return ?

Tags: php, массивы, return

Не судите строго, я начинающий PHP разработчик, вы можете объяснить подробно что делает этот код, если не сложно раскомментировать каждую строчку кода, за ранее благодарен, за ваши труды!

```
$arr = ["Ceylon", "Fish", "Apple", "MongoDB"]; 

function string_sort($a, $b){
    if (strlen($a) < strlen($b)) {
      return 1; 
    } elseif (strlen($a) == strlen($b)) { 
      return 0; 
    } else { 
      return -1; 
    }
}

usort($arr, 'string_sort');

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: usort — Сортирует массив по значениям используя пользовательскую функцию для сравнения элементов. Тут сортировка массива, для сортировки используют 1/0/-1 вот функция сравнивает и returt возвращает нужный цифру

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *зачем оператор return ?*

Для возврата значения из функции *(или метода)*, а так же для прекращения выполнения программы в текущей области видимости.

```
// Инициализация массива
$arr = ["Ceylon", "Fish", "Apple", "MongoDB"]; 

// Описание функции
function string_sort($a, $b){
    // Если длина строки переменной $a меньше чем $b
    if (strlen($a) < strlen($b)) {
        // Вернуть 1
        return 1;
        // Иначе если длина строки переменной $a равна $b
    } elseif (strlen($a) == strlen($b)) { 
        // Вернуть 0
        return 0;
        // Иначе если длина строки переменной $a больше $b
    } else {
        // Вернуть -1
        return -1; 
    }
}

// Сортировать массив
usort($arr, 'string_sort');

// И распечатать его дамп
var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: вы бы хоть написали, что код сортирует строки по их  длине. И если человек не понимает о чем речь, то он и не знает зачем требуется вернуть -1,0,1. ну и вдовесок что можно просто вернуть `strlen($a) - strlen($b)`, либо с `<=>`, и возможно с `mb_strlen`

Comment: @teran да знает он о назначении кода, а так же про оператор `<=>`, т.к. вчера у него была тема, и этот код собственно оттуда и взят :) [Как написать такой код на PHP с использованием оператора <=>](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/891880/185343) Поэтому я обобщил свой ответ до расстановки комментариев, ну и про return написал.